# Expectation of a square of a sum

Tags: self-study, nonparametric

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with density $f$ and let $\hat{f}$ be an estimator of $f$.
Is the following inequality direct from the standard properties of expectation and sup-norm?

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \lVert \hat{f}- \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})\rVert_\infty + 
\lVert \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})-f\rVert_\infty \right]^2 \leq  
2\mathbb{E}\lVert \hat{f}- \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})\rVert_\infty^2 + 
2\lVert \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})-f\rVert_\infty^2.$$

This inequality is found in page 44 of [Tsybakov's](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387790510) book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\le a^2+\overbrace{(a^2+b^2)}^{\ge 2ab}+b^2=2a^2+2b^2$$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \lVert \hat{f}- \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})\rVert_\infty + 
\lVert \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})-f\rVert_\infty \right]^2 \leq  
2\Bbb E[\lVert \hat{f}- \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})\rVert_\infty]^2 + 
2\lVert \mathbb{E}(\hat{f})-f\rVert_\infty^2.$$

Comment: Can you show me why 2ab need to be less than or equal the sum of squares? This is exactly what I was struggled with.

Comment: Hint:$$a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$$is equivalent to$$a^2+b^2-2ab\ge 0$$and then...